# Most efficient way to loop over python list and compare and adjust element values

Tags: python, loops, optimization, python-3.6

I have a list of elements with a certain attribute/variable. First of all I need to check if all attributes have the same value, if not I need to adapt this attribute for every element to the highes value. 
The thing is, it is not difficult to programm such a loop. However, I would like to know what the most efficient way is to do so.

My current approach works fine, but it loops through the list 2 times, has two local variables and just does not feel efficient enough.

I simplified the code. This is basically what I've got:

```
    biggest_value = 0
    re_calc = 0
    for _, element in enumerate(element_list):
        if element.value > biggest_value :
            biggest_value = element.value
            re_calc += 1
    if re_calc > 1:
        for _, element in enumerate(element_list):
            element.value = adjust_value(biggest_value)
            element_list(_) = element
```

The thing annoying me is the necessity of the "re_calc" variable. A simple check for the biggest value is no big deal. But this task consists out of 3 steps:
"Compare Attributes--> Finding Biggest Value --> possibly Adjust Others". However I do not want to loop over this list 3 times. Not even two times as my current suggestion does.

There has to be a more efficient way. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a sample input and desired output?

Comment: What does the `adjust_value` method?

Comment: And if you do not need the index of each item in your loop, you could avoid the use of `enumerate` and do `for element in element_list:`

Comment: @olinox14 , this question has a rather complicated answer. The attribute, which is checkt for, is an integer which indicates the level of discritization. All elements have to have the same level of discritization. So the "adjust_value" method takes that element and discretizes the element of the new set level of "detail". I hope this answer the question.

Comment: @iGian  Not really. All I can say is that the input is a list of elements and the desired attribute is an integer so element.value is an integer

Comment: @olinox14 ,  I think I will need it. As the current piece of code recalcultes the element with the biggest attribute as well, which is useless. So I guess I do need the index to check which element it was. But still, I did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: `re_calc > 1` means: do something if there is at least one element bigger than the first. Correct?

Comment: @iGian , pretty much, yeah. As I have to call evey element directly to get the value of the attribute, I need to loop through the list, instead of using the max() method. However, if the first element has the biggest value the if statement `if element.value > biggest_value :` wont trigger again and thus looking like every element has the same attribute value. So, to overcome this issue, I included the `re_calc`  variable

Comment: @iGian, I just realised a major flaw! If the first element has the biggest attribute, the code won`t realize it! Damn it.

Comment: I'd suggest, adapt your code to be tested with an array of integers (see my first comment), than a custom class. Or post a simplified class. This allows other people help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is just determing the largest value of the element_list. So an approach can be:
transform the element_list into a numpy array. Unfortunately you do not tell, how the list looks like.  But if the list contains numbers then
`L = np.array(element_list)`
can probably do it.
After that use `np.max(L)`. Numpy commands without for loops are usually much faster.

```
import numpy as np
nl = 10
L = np.random.rand(nl)
biggest_value = np.max(L)
L, biggest_value
```

gives

```
(array([0.70047074, 0.14160459, 0.75061621, 0.89013494, 0.70587705,
        0.50218377, 0.31197993, 0.42670057, 0.67869183, 0.04415816]),
 0.8901349369179461)
```

In the second for-loop it is not obvious what you want to achieve. Unfortunately you do not give an input and a desired output and do not not tell what `adjust_value` has to do. A minimal running code with data would be helpful to give a support.